# How to find the relation between track and track points after importing GPX data with ogr2ogr?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I've imported the gpx file into postgres db with postgis enabled using ogr2ogr:
`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=xxx user=xxx password=xxx dbname=xxx" "test.gpx"`

As expected, ogr2ogr created a bunch of tables, including `tracks` and `track_points`, and filled it with data from the provided GPX file. My question is: how can I now retrieve this data from database, preserving the relation between track and points? I thought that the `track_fid` column from `track_points` will point to the proper entry under `tracks` table but its value is always `0`. How can I then know which entries in `track_points` are part of specific `track`?

Comment: I made a test with a GPX file that has 6 tracks and I can see 6 different track_fid values in the tracks table, starting from 0. Does your GPX file contain more than one track?

Comment: No, just one. Are you able map track_fid values to the entries in tracks table?

Comment: I don't understand. If you have only one track, then all trackpoints belong to that single track.

Comment: Well, that is correct but what when I’ll run this ogr2ogr command a bunch of times with different gpx files. I end up with a bunch of entries in tracks and track_points tables. I’m looking for a way to determine which track points belong to which track.

Comment: You must add a new column into the PostGIS table and store the name of the source gpx file into the column. Maybe I would do that on the database side. Like import-update name where name is null-make a new import... Getting the same result with ogr2ogr commands and clever -sql parameters is possible but more tricky.